# Configuration of Django Channel with Redis secured with SSL

Tags: python, django, azure, redis, django-channels

I am facing the difficulty of configuring my Django application in Azure. I have a basic scenario where I track the file upload progress using the WebSocket. For WebSocket, I use Django Channels with Redis Channels. In my architecture, the Redis component is also used for another execution, and it is secured with SSL/TLS; therefore listens on port 6380.

In my application, I have the following configuration for Redis (Celery) and Django Channel (using Redis Channel)

*settings.py*

```py
# PORT 6379 for NON-SSL Connection and 6380 for SSL Connection
_broker_url = f'rediss://:{os.getenv("REDIS_PASS", "")}@{os.getenv("REDIS_HOST", "localhost")}:{os.getenv("REDIS_PORT", "6379")}'
CELERY_BROKER_URL = _broker_url
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = _broker_url
CELERY_BROKER_USE_SSL = {'ssl_cert_reqs': ssl.CERT_REQUIRED}
CELERY_REDIS_BACKEND_USE_SSL = {'ssl_cert_reqs': ssl.CERT_REQUIRED}

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [(os.getenv("REDIS_HOST", "127.0.0.1"), int(os.getenv("REDIS_PORT", 6379)))],
        },
    },
}
```

On my frontend I have the regular file upload form that opens the secured websocket:

```js
function createSocket(task_id) {
    const socket = new WebSocket(
      `wss://${config.backendUrl}/ws/tasks/${task_id}/`
    );

    socket.onmessage = function (e) {
      const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
      let status = data["message"]["status"];
      console.log(data);
      if (status === "SUCCESS") {
        api.get(targetUrl).then((value) => {
          handleUploadReload(value.data["files"]);
        });
        this.close();
      } else if (status === "FAILURE") {
        setError(data["message"]["error"]);
        this.close();
      }
    };

    socket.onclose = function (e) {
      console.log("Task socket closed");
    };

    socket.onerror = (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    };

    socket.onopen = (event) => {
      console.log(event);
    };

    return socket;
  }
```

Now when I try to upload the document and open the WebSocket, the file gets uploaded but the channel communication fails with the following error:

```
File "/tmp/lib/python3.10/site-packages/redis/asyncio/connection.py", line 852, in read_response
raise ConnectionError(redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error while reading from psm-redis.redis.cache.windows.net:6380 : (104, 'Connection reset by peer')
```

I tried to reconfigure the *settings.py* using the following configuration (which I found on the GitHub discussions, but they seems to be outdated):

```py
ssl_context = ssl.SSLContext()
ssl_context.check_hostname = False

redis_ssl_host = {
    'address': _broker_url,
    'ssl_context': ssl_context
}

CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": (redis_ssl_host,)
        },
    },
}
```

Does anyone know how to deploy the channels using rediss (more precisely, how to set up SSL for Django Channels)?

Comment: will give an example to connect to Azure  Redis when  SSL is enable  with python

Answer (score 0):

> I have referred this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-configure#access-ports) for azure radis connection, Azure Radis with [python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-python-get-started) and  [web socket](https://github.com/Vuka951/tutorial-code/blob/master/py-websockets/app.py)  git .Thank you @Vuka951.

- Enable [SSL](https://i.imgur.com/zEwl5g6.png), your [host name](https://i.imgur.com/v0dsbZV.png) , [accesskeykeys](https://i.imgur.com/dwF5H0O.png) and [CacheKeys](https://i.imgur.com/Hnr8bCw.png).

```py
result = r.set("Message",  "Hello!, Python is compatible with the cache!")

print("SET Message returned : " + str(result))
```

[image]

**In Azure:**

[image]

**With WebSocket:**

```py
connected = set()

async def server(websocket, path):
   
    connected.add(websocket)
    try:
        async for message in websocket:
            r.set("Message", message)
            for conn in connected:
                if conn != websocket:
                    cached_message = r.get("Message").decode("utf-8")
                    await conn.send(f'Got a new MSG FOR YOU: {cached_message}')
    finally:
      
        connected.remove(websocket)

myHostname = "yourhostname.redis.cache.windows.net"
myPassword = "primarykey"


r = redis.StrictRedis(host=myHostname, port=6380, password=myPassword, ssl=True)


result = r.ping()
print("Ping returned: " + str(result))

result = r.set("Message", "Hello!, Python is compatible with the cache!")
print("SET Message returned: " + str(result))

result = r.get("Message")
print("GET Message returned: " + result.decode("utf-8"))


start_server = websockets.serve(server, "localhost", 5000)

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Azure:**

[image]

**Set the key:**

```py
import  redis
redis_host = 'yourhostname.redis.cache.windows.net'

redis_port = 6380

redis_password = 'yourprimarykey'
key = 'myKey'

value = '866 13.90.202.154:13000'
redis_client = redis.StrictRedis(host=redis_host,  port=redis_port,  password=redis_password,  ssl=True)
redis_client.set(key,  value)

print(f"Successfully set the value of '{key}' in Azure Redis Cache.")

print(f"the vaule is {value} ")
```

[image]

[image]